# Java EE (Jakarta EE) и rest

Tags: java, java-ee, rest

Насколько принято или не принято писать `Rest API` с использованием `Java EE`?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Тут сложно ответить, так как у каждого будет свой опыт. Если в общем, то `Spring` появился как ответ на сложность `Java EE`. Разработчики посмотрели предложенную имплементацию и сказали, что все вот это не должно быть таким сложным. Другое дело, что со временем `Spring` очень сильно разросся и по сложности может уже посоперничать с `Java EE`. Но история повторяется по кругу - чтобы снизить порог вхождения, появился `Spring Boot`.

Справедливости ради, стоит отметить, что комитет JCP постарался учесть критику и максимально упростить все, что только можно; но процесс уже был запущен и разработчики так и не вернулись к `Java EE` в основной своей массе.

В общем-то, среднее приложение на стеке `Java EE` не так уж сильно и отличается от `Spring`-приложения. Хотя приложение на `Java EE` может работать только на Enterprise Application Server'е, а `Spring`-приложение на чем угодно (привет, `Tomcat`), да и вообще без сервера. Вследствие этого `Spring`-приложения более удобны в микросервисной архитектуре. С другой стороны, приложения на базе `Java EE` считаются более подходящими для написания монолитов, в силу чуть более удобной масштабируемости.

Кроме того, более частые релизы `Spring` (чуть ли не раз в месяц, против 2-3 лет в `Java EE`) позволяют первому учитывать все новые технологии и быть всегда немного впереди.

Как я заметил, новые проекты пишутся либо на `Spring`, либо на каких-то микро-фреймворках.  `Java EE` - это либо поддержка старых проектов, которые были начаты еще до появления `Spring`, либо что-то из банковской сферы или гос-учреждений, где смена технологий происходит очень медленно.

Но еще раз повторюсь, это только мой опыт, он может быть несколько специфичным.